# Postgresql extract multiple values into different columns

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, coalesce

I need to convert the information into columns however in some cases there can be multiple values for an answer.

I managed to concatenate the answers into a list with the following code:

```
'{' || ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG('"' || Question || '":' || Answer),',') || '}' AS key_value
```

Then using this column I could extract it with:

```
CAST(COALESCE(key_value::JSON ->> 'consumption_soda','0') AS INTEGER) AS soda_consumption,
CAST(COALESCE(key_value::JSON ->> 'consumption_water','0') AS INTEGER) AS water_consumption
```

However, when I wanted to extract soda_painpoints it will only return the first value.
Could you please help me find an answer to my problem?

!!!! UPDATE:
Just found out in the raw data that some answers are duplicated which has to be filtered out. Always the latest answer has to be used, except if the two answers happened in a different month. Then both should be extracted.
In one cell there could be multiple answers which need to be separated into columns. Or answers can be in different rows.

The starting format of the raw data table:
[image]

And I would like to have a flat output something like this where pain points could have a total of 8 values maximum -> 8 soda_painpoints column:
[image]

Comment: Those are actually not NULL, just separated in excel for easier view.

Answer (score 0):

First, to concatenate the answers into a jsonb object, you should use `jsonb_object_agg(Question, Answer) AS key_value` instead of `'{' || ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG('"' || Question || '":' || Answer),',') || '}' AS key_value`.

Then the Answer '1 5 8 7' for the `soda_painpoints` Question seems to be a string which concatenates a list of integers (1, 5, 8, 7) separated by a space character. In this case, you can store the Answer as a simple jsonb numeric value or as a jsonb array depending on the type of the Answer value :

```
SELECT jsonb_object_agg( Question
                       , CASE 
                           WHEN jsonb_typeof(to_jsonb(Answer)) = 'number'
                           THEN Answer :: text
                           ELSE regexp_split_to_array(Answer, '\s+') :: text
                         END
                       ) AS key_value
```

Doing so, the value associated to the key `soda_painpoints` will be a jsonb array of integers.

Comment: Thanks for the code,
I checked it now, but it returns an error:
ERROR: CASE types integer[] and integer cannot be matched ...

All the columns in the table are stored as TEXT (Question and Answer)
What could be the problem?

Comment: Yes indeed, it is not possible to return various data types in the same `CASE`. So I've updated the answer while converting all the Answers into text before creating the jsonb object. This solution should be ok if you don't mind storing the Answers as text in the jsonb object.

Comment: I updated the problem as I just found out there were several problems with the data.
Thanks for your modified code, it worked however I struggle to find a solution on how to extract values from JSON data. Maybe JSON is not even the best solution for this problem. I welcome your suggestions.